# Weird behaviour when using dynamic_rnn and providing sequence_length argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have noticed something strange when using `dynamic_rnn` in Tensorflow.

Until now, I didn't provide a `sequence_length` argument, I would just feed the input data and targets.
Recently I have tried supplying the `sequence_length` argument, as I understand it is the correct thing to do.
However, the behaviour of the model is drastically different, which puzzles me a little.

I have trained a model for sequence prediction: the network, given a sequence of binary vectors (not one-hot), tries to predict the next vector.
When I don't provide `sequence_length` to generate a prediction, I get this kind of output:
[The top image is the input sequence, the bottom is the prediction output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tjwO.png)

It's not super good, but it seems to follow the input (or at least it tries)

When I use the same trained model, but this time I provide the `sequence_length` argument, I get this kind of output:
[The top image is the input sequence, the bottom is the prediction output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVh9T.png)

It's super bad, it's like it is copying the first output throughout.

I have triple checked: the sequence length I provide is not zero, and it is the correct length value.
I observe the same problem both when I provide `sequence_length`during training, and when I do not.
If I am not mistaken, I should get approximately the same thing with and without `sequence_length` argument if I use the same weights in both cases ?

I am using Tensorflow 1.0.0

Has anyone noticed anything strange using `dynamic_rnn` and prividing the `sequence_length` values ? Or on the contrary has anyone checked that they get the same results with and without `sequence_length` ?
Any idea why I get strange outputs like that ?

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: If you want to provide sequence lengths when generating predictions, you should provide them during training as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I should have made it clearer that i have the exact same problem both when ``sequence_length`` is provided during training and when it's not. I'll update my post

Comment: But anyway, according to [Tensorflow's docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn), it shouldn't change much, since the only thing providing ``sequence_length`` changes it to copy the outputs and hidden states after the end of the sequence, or am I missing something ?